# Business::PayPal::IPN (Perl) -- PayPal keeps sending!

Tags: perl, paypal

I'm using Business::PayPal::IPN, basically just like the example in the documentation.  The verification is basically working, but the only problem is that PayPal keeps sending the verifications repeatedly for the same transaction.  Is there something I'm supposed to do to tell it to stop?  I'm wondering if there's a problem with my HTTP response, but the module should handle that, no?

Comment: AFAIK `Business::PayPal::IPN` doesn't return anything to PayPal, your IPN handler needs to return an HTTP status code on its own. The module does talk to PayPal to verify the IPN data but that's separate from what you return to PayPal from your IPN handler. Try returning 200 (OK) as your status and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, that helped, thanks!  I ended up using the CGI module and passing the $cgi object to the IPN contructor, then using $cgi again to send a response.